# Compile Header Files

Tags: c, compilation, makefile, header

I have the following files to compile:

```
cc -g    -c -o add_clnt.o add_clnt.c
cc -g    -c -o add_client.o add_client.c initfunction.c
cc -g    -c -o add_xdr.o add_xdr.c
cc -g    -o add_client  add_clnt.o add_client.o add_xdr.o -lnsl
cc -g    -c -o add_svc.o add_svc.c
cc -g    -c -o add_server.o add_server.c
cc -g    -o add_server  add_svc.o add_server.o add_xdr.o -lnsl
```

but this is not possible because I get the following error:

```
cc -g    -c -o add_clnt.o add_clnt.c
cc -g    -c -o add_client.o add_client.c initfunction.c
cc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [new] Fehler 1
```

initfunction.c is connected with add_client.c over a initfunction.h, so it provides additional functions.

Can somebody tell me how to compile this ?

Gruß, Andre

Comment: Aren't *all* the files you link together "connected" in the end? Header-files and source-files are actually not *connected* in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
cc -g    -c -o add_client.o add_client.c initfunction.c
```

to

```
cc -g    -c -o add_client.o add_client.c 
cc -g    -c -o initfunction.o initfunction.c
```

Then add `initfunction.o` to the list of objects to link.

Comment: Still get the error "cc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files"